# gcloud dataflow: how to copy mysql data into firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow

How can I load data from a mysql database to google firestore and stream mysql database to capture update or delete row and update firestore database?

how can i use gcloud dataflow or other gcloud solution to perform this activity

Comment: Please see the solution mentioned on the link for mysql to BQ, similar solution can be used for firestore as a sink https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-move-data-from-mysql-to-bigquery

Comment: thx i'm going to take a look